# org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigException: Missing required configuration "bootstrap.servers" which has no default value

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I'm getting this error when running my producer class in *Eclipse*:
***org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigException: Missing required configuration "bootstrap.servers" which has no default value***

Here is my producer class:

```
public class SimpleProducer {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    try {
        String topicName = "mytopic";
        String key = "key1";
        String value = "Value-1";

        Properties prop = new Properties();
        prop.put("bootstrap.server","localhost:9092");
        prop.put("key.serializer","org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
        prop.put("value.serializer","org.apache.kafka.cpmmon.serialization.StringSerializer");

        Producer<String, String> producer = new KafkaProducer<>(prop);

        ProducerRecord<String, String> record = new ProducerRecord<>(topicName,key,value);
        producer.send(record);
        producer.close();
        System.out.println("SimpleProducer Completed.");
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Any pointers on how to fix it?

Comment: You misspelled the property key `"bootstrap.servers"`. To avoid this mistake in the future, use the constant `ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG` instead.

Comment: Why do you never, ever, accept any answers to your questions, OP?

Answer (score 11):

Use the following and avoid using hardcoded values

For

```
prop.put("bootstrap.server","localhost:9092");
prop.put("key.serializer","org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
prop.put("value.serializer","org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
```

Use

```
prop.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServer);
prop.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class.getName());
prop.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class.getName());
```

**ProducerConfig** will be found in **org.apache.kafka.clients.producer** package

Comment: I tried this example but there was a typo: cpmmon => common. I cannot eddit the post because is less than 8 characters.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out @ordago I have updated it

Answer (score 9):

Just change the

`prop.put("bootstrap.server","localhost:9092");`

to

`prop.put("bootstrap.servers","localhost:9092");`

And in your code

```
prop.put("value.serializer",
         "org.apache.kafka.cpmmon.serialization.StringSerializer");
```

the `common` is not spelled correctly, the right package is
`org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer`

Answer (score 0):

Here two observations found

### 1.

Replace

```
prop.put("bootstrap.server","localhost:9092");
```

by

```
prop.put("bootstrap.servers","localhost:9092");
```

> bootstrap.server   -- **incorrect**
>
> bootstrap.server**s**  -- **correct**

### 2.

Replace

```
org.apache.kafka.cpmmon.serialization.StringSerializer
```

By

```
org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
```